# How to plug Apache to several ldap servers with mod_authnz_ldap?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, ldap, mod-auth-ldap

The apache mod_authnz_ldap [AuthLDAPURL](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapurl) directive can have several ldap URIs as showed in the doc:

```
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap1.example.com ldap2.example.com/dc=..."
```

However, if I need different bind information ([AuthLDAPBindDN](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapbinddn) and [AuthLDAPBindPassword](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#authldapbinddn)) for the different ldap servers, how can I achieve this? It seems there can be only one of each. Also, how can I match a password with a ldap URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the [AuthnProviderAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_authn_core.html) directive.

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-alias1>
    AuthLDAPBindDN cn=youruser,o=ctx
    AuthLDAPBindPassword yourpassword
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.host/o=ctx
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<AuthnProviderAlias ldap ldap-other-alias>
    AuthLDAPBindDN cn=yourotheruser,o=dev
    AuthLDAPBindPassword yourotherpassword
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://other.ldap.host/o=dev?cn
</AuthnProviderAlias>

Alias "/secure" "/webpages/secure"
<Directory "/webpages/secure">
    AuthBasicProvider ldap-other-alias  ldap-alias1
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "LDAP Protected Place"
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```